# java regex take variable between two tag

Tags: java, regex

I am very new in regex and need your help. I wanna take numbers and letters between two span.

```
        <span>454.000 $</span>
```

I wanna take 454.000 $. There are 12 space before . Please help me.

Comment: Any particular reason that you are using regex to parse HTML? In general that is pretty frowned upon.

Comment: $number = strip_tags($HTMLBLOB);  \o/

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Regexp:

```
\s+<.+>(.+)<.+>
```

Input:

```
            <span>454.000 $</span>
```

Output:

```
454.000 $
```

JAVA CODE:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\s+<.+>(.+)<.+>";
final String string = "            <span>454.000 $</span>";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/2zg5Ws/1

Comment: sorry but I don't have enogh reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

Capturing group using pattern matching is something like below

```
String x = "   <span>454.000 $</span>    ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<span>(.*?)</span>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(">> "+ m.group(1)); // output 454.000 $
}
```

But for such cases I always prefer to use the `replaceAll()` as it is shorter version of code:

```
String num = x.replaceAll(".*<span>(.*?)</span>.*", "$1");
// num has 454.000 $
```

For the replace it is actually capturing the group from the text and replacing the whole text with that group (`$1`). This solution depends upon how your input string is.